# Comparative logic in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

Good morning everyone!

I have the following problem: We have a system that creates change logs about tables in a environment and sends those logs as messages to kafka.
Kafka delivers these messages to NIFI and NIFI uses this to alter tables in another environment. I only have control over what happens in the NIFI.

The problem is that, by their nature, Kafka messages do not arrive in the order in which the changes were performed in the environment of the source tables.
The case where two updates in a row on the same object in one of the tables is feasible and therefore there is a risk that the latest update arrives before the obsolete update and so NIFI overwrites more recent data with outdated data.

I thought of using the kafka.timestamp attribute as a way to avoid this. Every time I record, or update information in the target environment, I also record the timestamp. Reading this field is also no problem for me.
I intend, therefore, before writing new information to a line, to read the timestamp field and see if the current timestamp is greater than the line's timestamp, and write only if that is true.
The problem is that I have no idea how to do such comparative logic in NIFI. Does anyone know if this is possible? I can't use script processors (I don't have authorization and they have restrictions for production use).

Many thanks to anyone who can help, and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1):

if you have any access to the application that reads from the tables events and sends the event to kafka.

All you have to do is to specify some key (maybe the row id) and than the messages will be sent to the some kafka partition which guarantees the order

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to it, only to nifi.